# SLComposeViewControllerResultDone when no network

Tags: ios

When I check twitter(iOS5 & 6) when there is no network,it is returning me the SLComposeViewControllerResultDone in the completion handler.is there any solution to show the successful result?
Any help could be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation

`The handler has a single parameter that indicates whether the user finished or cancelled composing the post. This block is not guaranteed to be called on any particular thread.`

The value of the parameter could be

- **SLComposeViewControllerResultCancelled** : Means That the view controller is dismissed without sending the post. For example, the user selects Cancel or the account is not available.
- **SLComposeViewControllerResultDone** : The view controller is dismissed and the message is being sent in the background. This occurs when the user selects Done.

So in your case I think you need to check for the reachability either inside the  completion handler or before presenting the `SLComposeViewController` and show appropriate message.

Comment: Hi prasad, Thanks for your reply..i have tried your suggestion,no use of that,but here condition is like i am in the twitter page and network is off, i am getting @"try again" alert message after that if i click on cancel i couldnt handle that scenario

Comment: it is not working if i place reachability inside the block.anyway i am checking the reachability outside,now i have overcome the no network issue.thank you prasad